# Incorporating Additional Devices in Custom PCB

Tags: pcb-design, stm32, stepper-motor, bluetooth-low-energy

I've been tasked with designing a custom PCB based on a prototype I made this past year. This prototype uses ST's NUCLEO-F030R8T6 development board along with some stepper motor drivers (AMIS-30543) and a BLE module (HM-10). As I understand it, I'll have to use the NUCLEO's electrical schematic to incorporate the development board's MCU (STM32F030R8T6) in this custom PCB. I came across [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/42840/how-to-go-from-a-development-board-to-a-production-board) and it has provided some great information but I still have some questions of my own.

My question is what do I do about the stepper motor drivers and BLE module? Should I be doing the same for them? The BLE module has its own AT firmware, so if I am to 'break it down' for the PCB then how would I flash it with that firmware? I'm not sure if the stepper motor drivers have their own firmware (sorry, I'm extremely new to embedded and learning as I go), so if they do, same question as the BLE module.

I could design the PCB to simply have pinouts/sections to solder the BLE module and drivers to, but I want to do a good job at this.

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: There is nothing distasteful, impractical, or immoral about using modules on a finished PCB.  The usual motivation to _incorporate_ a modules contents into a custom PCB is an effort to reduce cost and control the BOM.  Sometimes it's worth it.  Sometimes not.  It's not unreasonable to incorporate a section (like the uC), and use modules for other stuff (like a Bluetooth module).  It's up to you.

Comment: I'd avoid creating a new custom board with all those components, unless a) necessary, b) have much experience, and c) have lots of free time. Just the BLE board for example, could have 500 hours of engineering, re-engineering, and certification time from industry veterans. Using modules outright is like "standing on the shoulders of giants" - a great thing for little effort.

Comment: The BLE Chip will be hardest to correctly integrate and then certify, so a module makes lots of sense.  Socketed stepper drivers can help fix a failure though the sockets are an issue.  Since you are new to board design you might keep those.  Putting the MCU on the board would be a great learning experience, chose QFP *not* QFN for first time success.  But this is really a question of *opinion*.

Comment: BTW HM-10 is *ancient*.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. @ChrisStratton is there a recommended replacement for the HM-10? It's working well for our purposes, but if its ancient then sourcing it may be tough down the road.

Comment: I'd look at the MDBT series modules with the nRF52... you may be able to create a board which supports either BLE option.  Long run its also possible you could use something like the nRF52 to do the STM32's job as well, since apart from the radio they are comparable, but of course more integrated software can be a project in and of itself, and not necessarily the one you want to engage in right now.

Comment: A reliable Bluetooth solution is rare and precious.  Like a friendly, non-pooping unicorn.  Don't discard it unless it bites.